# how to get Revenue using programming in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.4.2

how can we get the Revenue using **API** or Without using API programming in Magento 2.4,
like below image,

[image]

I have tried using **API**, and below is my code.
**webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/custom/custom-api/post/" method="GET">
        <service class="Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\CustomInterface" method="getTotalRevenue"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**custom.php**
/var/www/html/m2_new_staging/app/code/Rental/Totalrevenue/Model/Api

```
<?php

namespace Rental\Totalrevenue\Model\Api;
use Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Custom
{
  protected $_collectionFactory;
  protected $logger;

  public function __construct(
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
  )
  {

    $this->logger = $logger;
  }

  /**
  * @inheritdoc
  */

  public function getTotalRevenue()
  {
      //pass ID parameter as you need from store or website
      $isFilter = $this->getRequest()->getParam(
          'store'
      ) || $this->getRequest()->getParam(
          'website'
      ) || $this->getRequest()->getParam(
          'group'
      );
      $period = $this->getRequest()->getParam('period', Period::PERIOD_24_HOURS); // 1y, 2y
      / @var $collection Collection /
      $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->addCreateAtPeriodFilter(
          $period
      )->calculateTotals(
          $isFilter
      );
      if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('store')) {
          $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $this->getRequest()->getParam('store'));
      } else {
          if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('website')) {
              $storeIds = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite($this->getRequest()->getParam('website'))->getStoreIds();
              $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', ['in' => $storeIds]);
          } else {
              if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('group')) {
                  $storeIds = $this->_storeManager->getGroup($this->getRequest()->getParam('group'))->getStoreIds();
                  $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', ['in' => $storeIds]);
              } elseif (!$collection->isLive()) {
                  $collection->addFieldToFilter(
                      'store_id',
                      ['eq' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(Store::ADMIN_CODE)->getId()]
                  );
              }
          }
      }
      $collection->load();
      $totals = $collection->getFirstItem();
      return $totals->getRevenue();
      //return 'Total Revenue $param ' . $param;
  }

  public function getPost($value)
  {
    $response = ['success' => false];

    try {
      // Your Code here
   
      $response = ['success' => true, 'message' => $value];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      $response = ['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()];
      $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
    }
    $returnArray = json_encode($response);
    return $returnArray;
  }

  
}
```

**CustomInterface.php**

**/var/www/html/m2_new_staging/app/code/Rental/Totalrevenue/Api**

```
<?php

namespace Rental\Totalrevenue\Api;

interface CustomInterface
{

/**
 * GET for Post api
 * @param string $param
 * @return string
 */
public function getTotalRevenue();

}
```

**here i have code `$period = $this->getRequest()->getParam('period', Period::PERIOD_24_HOURS);`, can we have changes that period like, today, last 3 months?**

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Path `Magento\Backend\Block\Dashboard\Totals`
This block is responsible form returning the Revenue to the dashboard  `Magento_Backend::dashboard\totalbar.phtml`.check this line `$this->addTotal(__('Revenue'), $totals->getRevenue())`;

Comment: so can we get this revenue using REST API?

Comment: Yes you can need to find out is there any Magento API providing this Info If not then you have to create your own Api.